# Android - set adapter inside retrofit

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

In a `Fragment`, in the `onCreateView` method, I set the adapter in this way:

```
final BusStopAdapter mAdapter = new BusStopAdapter(nearbyBusStations);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Then there is a retrofit method which set the nearbyBusStations in the adapter:

```
 service.getJson(origin, dest).enqueue(new Callback<DirectionResults>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DirectionResults> call, Response<DirectionResults> response) {
                Route routeA = response.body().getRoutes().get(0);
                Legs legs = routeA.getLegses().get(0);
                nearbyBusStations.add(new NearbyBusStation(currentItem.getName(), String.valueOf(legs.getDistance().getValue()), legs.getDuration().getText()));
            mAdapter.swapItems(nearbyBusStations);
               mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(nearbyBusStations.size() - 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DirectionResults> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("CallBack", " Throwable is " + t);
            }
        });
```

These lines of code works, but the problem is that I want to clear the `mRecyclerView` in another `AsyncTask`. I've tried some ways but nothing works. 
I need to clear the `mRecyclerView` because I have to refresh the near bus stop station.

Comment: can you please post code of clearing recyclerview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply clear your arraylist and notify your adapter where you want to clear your recyclerview.

Example:-

```
nearbyBusStations.clear();
mAdapter.setnotifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope its help you..

Comment: I don't know if is normal, but it works only with nearbyBusStations.clear(). Thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should clear your list and notify the adapter as below

```
nearbyBusStations.clear();
mAdapter.setnotifyDataSetChanged();
```